# Authenticating SpringBoot Application on Laravel Database

Tags: laravel, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, eloquent

We have an application made in traditional Laravel but now starting another project on top of the Laravel application database.

Starting with Authentication. Just wondering how I can log in using the same method Laravel is using in Spring boot? Below is the algorithm used by the Laravel team.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spring does support BCrypt algorithm, and also customized hash algorithm.
You can easily do that by wiring the new Spring application to your existing DB, define new **User** entity corresponding to your DB, and a **UserDetailsService** in which you can inject your customized **PasswordEncoder**

Find more here :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/servlet/configuration/java.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/features/authentication/password-storage.html